# Weird Python Threading Behaviour

Tags: python, multithreading

Seeing something a little weird which has been hard to replicate.

In short I read links from a file into a list:

```
with open(filename) as f:
    LinkList = f.readlines()
```

And each position on this list has a set point. The files are static so they're not changing.

```
site1 = LinkList[1]
site2 = LinkList[2]
site3 = LinkList[3]
```

This will either contain a link to the site or an "x" to indicate the site doesn't need to run.

To track whether the threads are running I use a 1 or 0 so I start with

```
Site1running = 0
Site2running = 0
Site3running = 0
```

Then I start the threads if there's actually a link present. The reason for this is I might later set this back to 0 and spawn a new thread to run again. This next part loops and starts the threads up to begin with and will restart them later if they're set to '0'.

```
if True:

  if "google.com" in site1:
    if Site1running == 0:
      Site1running = 1
      GoogleThread = Thread(target = CheckGoogle)
      GoogleThread.start()

  if "Bing.com" in site2:
    if Site2running == 0:
      Site2running = 1
      BingThread = Thread(target = CheckBing)
      BingThread.start()
```

This works 99% of the time. But I'm seeing a weird issue when I very first start the script.

It's loading the same file. It's reading the text file and getting the links fine. But it will randomly miss starting some of these threads at all. Won't begin a the start of the thread and won't start later on.

Starting and stopping it a few times seems to get it working so I'm assuming this is some kind of timing issue. It's sometimes starting the thread if something else hasn't already happened first.

Seems to happen the more sites are being used and tends to be the ones further down the list.

The really infuriating part is the fact that starting and stopping it fixes it. It'll start all the threads and keep restarting them later.

If anyone can shed some light on this I'd really appreciate it. The only thing I can think is smother it in time.sleeps because some weird timing issue is the only thing which seems to fit. Logically I don't understand why but I can't think why else starting and stopping it would change anything.

Comment: Are you properly handling exceptions in your threads - IIRC threads can fail silently unless your code does something to report the exception (or perhaps that's multiprocessing threads?).

Comment: I am. But even if I wasn't the problem happens when it first starts this cycle there wouldn't be time for a thread to break before the rest should start.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time but I don't think it's a thread failing. They all boot up in under a second to start with there's no time for one to fail before the others should be starting up.

Comment: Why don't you add logging in main when a thread is started, and in the thread functions when they start/exit, so a trace is created of what is happening that you can later go back and look at. Could your threads be waiting on a semaphore (or something which uses a semaphore? Does the thread function run at all - get it to do something visible the first thing it does, now is that visible when the problem happens? The problem is 99.999% in your code - so you will have to instrument it to find out what is actually happening.

Comment: It does actually display to the console I have a print "starting site xyz" which is how I know that randomly restarting will get it to load.

Comment: As it goes wrong infrequently and not when you are looking, adding logging will allow you to understand the sequence of events that happened once you have spotted that something has gone wrong.

Comment: so the 'starting site' message is _always_ printed by the thread, even when the thread doesn't do anything useful?

Comment: It will say "Starting site" XYZ for whatever sites work. The ones which do go on to run show up the missing ones don't I restart it a few times and then I'll see the missing ones show in the console and they'll go on to run normally.

Comment: Well I can't debug it from here. Add print statements to show that the mainline is actually trying to start the threads, anything else you can think of to understand what is actually happening.

Comment: I really appreciate you taking the time I'm smothering everything with outputs so I can try and get some kind of idea on what's going on. It's like trying to find a needle in a haystack. A haystack of needles. Rusty needles.

Comment: Needles are easy - use a magnet.